# BigQuery PHP Client Libraries getRows (mapping column in datatable)

Tags: php, google-bigquery

I want to get response from bigquery without loop property f,v

```
$response = $bigquery->jobs->query($projectId, $request);
$rows = $response->getRows();

foreach($rows as $data){
            $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$data->f[6]->v);
            $response[$count]["app_id"] = $data->f[0]->v;
            $response[$count]["uid"] = $data->f[1]->v;
            $response[$count]["account"] = $data->f[2]->v;
            $response[$count]["action"] = $data->f[9]->v;
            $response[$count]["ip"] = $data->f[5]->v;
            $response[$count]["status"] = $data->f[11]->v;
            $response[$count]["created_date"] = $date;

}
```

Expected

```
$response = $bigquery->jobs->query($projectId, $request);
$rows = $response->getRows();
echo $rows[0]["app_id"];
```

How to? Is it possible? Could anyone help me find the solution?

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Comment: good, but you have several questions where you didn't took complete action, revise those

Comment: make sure that you choose the good answer, you need to choose good answers where you have answers. If the question is no longer good, and no answer then delete it.

Comment: I have already revised.

Comment: I will post an answer soon for this PHP question, hold on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using this query as example:

```
SELECT repository_url, 
       repository_has_downloads 
FROM   publicdata:samples.github_timeline
LIMIT  10
```

First you need to build a `schema_keys` array from the "name" property.

```
$fields = $response->getSchema()->getFields();
$schema_keys = array_flip(array_map(function($o){ return $o->name; }, $fields));
```

This would hold results column name ==> index number:

```
Array
(
    [repository_url] => 0
    [repository_has_downloads] => 1
)
```

Then when you loop:

```
foreach ($rows as $r) {
    // you need to convert the TableRow in TableCell here
    $table_cell = $r->getF();
    // then you can read columns from it like this
    echo $table_cell[$schema_keys['repository_url']]->getV();
    echo $table_cell[$schema_keys['repository_has_downloads']]->getV();
}
```